# How to split a string into a list but not brackets?

Tags: python, regex

Sorry about the title - I wasn't sure how to word it. Anyway, I'm writing a markup language compiler in python that compiles into HTML. Example:

```
-(a){href:"http://www.google.com"}["Click me!"]
```

Compiles into:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click me!</a>
```

It's all working great until nested tags are introduced:

```
-(head)[
    -(title)[Nested tags]
]

-(body)[
    -(div)[
        -(h1)[Nested tags]
        -(p)[Paragraph]
    ]
]
```

Which produces:

```
<title>Nested tags</title>
<h1>Nested tags</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Because the program splits commands using `code.split("-")`, It is splitting the commands insides of the bodies of other commands. When I added `print statement` into the compiler code, I got:

```
(head)[
(title)[Nested tags]
]
(body)[
(div)[
(h1)[Nested tags]
(p)[Paragraph]
]
]
```

Each line is interpreted as a different command so my regexps (`\((.+)\)\[(.+)\]` and `\((.+)\)\{(.+)\}\[(.+)\]`) do not match something like `head[`. I thought the best solution was to have it split '-' unless it was in the body of a command, making the above produce:

```
(head)[-(title)[Nested tags]
(body)[-(div)[-(h1)[Nested tags]-(p)[Paragraph]]]
```

Then run the same code for each command within each block.

TL;DR: Make input:

```
"-abc-def[-ignore-me]-ghi"
```

Produce:

```
["abc", "def", "[-ignore-me]", "ghi"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `if code == "-abc-def[-ignore-me]-ghi": return ["abc", "def", "[-ignore-me]", "ghi"]` :)

Comment: @Scorpion_God I thought you were giving my a proper answer at first :)

Comment: I don't think any regular expression can work, as your markup is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). You may need to use a parser library.

Comment: So is the syntax `-(tag){attributes}[content]`? Where `[content]` is optional and `attributes` looks like `name:value, name:value...`?

Comment: @Blckknght You're right, of course, but why don't we try to make our own?

Comment: @scorpion_God I should probably have added a proper explaination but yes, your pretty much correct. -(tag){attribute0:val,attribute1:val}[body]. Attributes are optional but tag and body are not.

Comment: So no `</br>`? Or any other self-closing tag that doesn't have content?

Comment: @Scorpion_God I hadn't got that far :) but could maybe add a percent sign or some other character to the end of the command to indicate a self closing tag.

Comment: @Blckknght any particular (python) libraries you would recommend?

Comment: Does my answer work like how you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this dodgy code works similar to what you want:

```
import re

re_name = re.compile(r'-\(([^)]+)\)')
re_args = re.compile(r'{([^}]+)}')

def parse(chars, history=[]):
  body = ''
  while chars:
    char = chars.pop(0)
    if char == '[':
      name = re_name.search(body).group(1)
      args = re_args.search(body)
      start = '<'+name
      if args:
        for arg in args.group(1).split(','):
          start += ' '+arg.strip().replace(':', '=')
      start += '>'
      end = '</'+name+'>'
      history.append(start)
      history.append(parse(chars))
      history.append(end)
      body = ''
      continue
    if char == ']':
      return body.strip()
    body += char
  return history

code = '''
-(head)[
    -(title)[Nested tags]
    -(random)[Stuff]
]

-(body){class:"nav", other:stuff, random:tests}[
    -(div)[
        -(h1)[Nested tags]
        -(p)[Paragraph]
    ]
]
'''

parsed = parse(list(code))
print(''.join(parsed))
```